# Keycloak login theme not updating for a specific realm

Tags: themes, keycloak

I have a keycloak installed on my kubernetes cluster and the application is running normally.

I have 2 realms, master and the second one is Accenture-of-Dev.

Im trying to change the keycloak login theme of accenture-of-dev realm because today the theme is the base/basic theme of keycloak:[Accenture-of-dev login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CFlx.png).

I've tried to change the theme using the keycloak admin U.I of that realm, and i changed the login theme from basic to Keycloak:[Realm Login Page Changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAGsC.png).

After that i saved the changes and the u.i returns me the changes are applied succesfully, but when i reloaded my realm login page, the change doesnt work and the basic theme is showed again.

I tested this using my master realm and its works normally, when i changed the login theme from basic to keycloak, logout and login again on the realm login page, its works and the theme changed, but this isnt happening on accenture-of-dev realm. What im missing here? Im using keycloak version 20.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable theme caching when starting Keycloak?

From the [*Creating a theme* documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#creating-a-theme):

```bash
bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --spi-theme-static-max-age=-1 --spi-theme-cache-themes=false --spi-theme-cache-templates=false
```

These options also be configured in `conf/keycloak.conf`.